# JMenuBar not showing up

Tags: java, swing, menu, jmenubar

I'm not sure why my JMenuBar isn't showing up.The other 2 panels that I add show up just fine.I'm not sure if it has something to do with borderLayout being picky or what. I'm sure(hope) it is something small. I'm just learning how to create GUIs so that is entirely possible. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
    public homeGUI()
{
    super("Pixfile Photo Manager");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,5));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    initComponants();
    initHeaderPanel();
    buildFileListPanel();
    createMenuBar();

    add(headerPanel, "Center");
    add(fileListPanel, "West");

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void createMenuBar(){
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu();
    manageMenu = new JMenu();
    aboutMenu = new JMenu();

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(manageMenu);
    menuBar.add(aboutMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without text, the `JMenu`s will not appear in the menu bar:

```
fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
manageMenu = new JMenu("Manage");
aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");
```

Aside: Avoid using magic numbers for window close operations (3 = `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: Thank you Reimeus! That was it.